# Running MixRadio's songs on 3rd party music player on wp8.1

Tags: mixradio

I am an app developer and planing to make a music app for wp8.1 but while scaning the songs the songs downloaded from mixradio displays as unknown album. What shall i do for it? To make it properly arranged in respective albums? Please guide me for the same as thousands of people are having their collection filled with mix radio songs.. Your help on this topic will be appriciated by me and as well as thousnds of awaiting lumians... Waiting for your reply..

Answer (score 1):

You can get the media details through the [XNA Media Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) if you're using Silverlight or [KnownFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.knownfolders.musiclibrary.aspx) on WinRT projects. Both of these read MixRadio MP3s successfully normally, so please give more detail - for example: what type of project you're using, the code you're using, details of the songs you're having trouble with.